# GitHub changes repository to the wrong language

Tags: git, github, repository, github-linguist

I know this isn't a huge deal, but I like my GitHub to be linguistically diversified. I wrote a project in [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_%28Apple_programming_language%29) and when I commit it says it's in [Objective-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C).

I think it might be because the Parse frameworks are written in Objective-C and it detects that, but is there a way to change the display language on the main repository page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the language of a repository on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597892/how-to-change-the-language-of-a-repository-on-github)

Answer (score 169):

I found the simplest thing was to create a file called `.gitattributes` in the root folder of my repository, and give it these contents:

```
* linguist-vendored
*.js linguist-vendored=false
```

This example tells GitHub/Linguist to ignore all files, and then just look at .js files.  My project, https://github.com/aim12340/jQuery-Before-Ready, was listed as HTML because the HTML example files were bigger than the JavaScript files.  This file fixes it for me and now it's listed as JavaScript.

Comment: just create a new .gitattributes file under repo root folder with content above, instant fix !

Comment: Maybe a dummy comment, but in case you wonder what to do exactly, 1. Follow the guidance of @Gob00st in his comment, and 2. Replace ".js" by the extension of your main language files.

Comment: I had a similar problem for my ASP.NET core project. Github thought it was a javascript repo because of the amount of js files under the www folder. Adding .gitattributes file with [webprojectfolder]/wwwroot/* linguist-vendored fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: I added the `.gitattributes` file with the above contents, except that I replaced the `*.js` with `*.arr` because those files were misidentified as `Pyret`. Now the repo is allegedly 100% `Pyret` and there's no `Python` left, so it had the opposite effect for me…

Comment: @Lampe2020 Try changing the .js to .py if you want it to be shown as Python.

Answer (score 79):

As mentioned in the [GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/articles/my-repository-is-marked-as-the-wrong-language/)

> GitHub uses the open source [Linguist library](https://github.com/github/linguist) to determine file languages for syntax highlighting and repository statistics.
>   Some files are hard to identify, and sometimes projects contain more library and vendor files than their primary code.

So you need to check with [`github/linguist#troubleshooting`](https://github.com/github/linguist#troubleshooting) in order to fix this situation.

> The percentages are calculated based on the bytes of code for each language as reported by the [List Languages API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-languages).
>   If the bar is reporting a language that you don't expect:
>
> - Click on the name of the language in the stats bar to see a list of the files that are identified as that language.
> - If you see files that you didn't write, consider moving the files into one of the [paths for vendored code](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/vendor.yml), or use the [manual overrides feature](https://github.com/github/linguist#overrides) to ignore them.
> - If the files are being misclassified, search for [open issues](https://github.com/github/linguist/issues) to see if anyone else has already reported the issue. Any information you can add, especially links to public repositories, is helpful.
> - If there are no reported issues of this misclassification, [open an issue](https://github.com/github/linguist/issues) and include a link to the repository or a sample of the code that is being misclassified.

---

Update February 2017 (one year later):

The article "**[How to Change Repo Language in GitHub](https://medium.com/black-tech-diva/how-to-change-repo-language-in-github-c3e07819c5bb#.ckavav4en)**" from [**Monica Powell**](https://twitter.com/waterproofheart)

> Upon researching how to resolve GitHub misclassifying the language of your projects I found out the solution is as simple as telling GitHub which files to ignore.
>
> While you still want to commit these files to GitHub and therefore can’t use a `.gitignore` **you can tell GitHub’s linguist which files to ignore in a `.gitattributes` file**

```
static/* linguist-vendored
```

> This one-line file told GitHub to ignore all of my files in my `static/` folder which is where CSS and other assets are stored for a Flask app

The ["Using `.gitattributes`" section](https://github.com/github/linguist#using-gitattributes) does illustrate how to mark wrong languages.
For instance:

> Checking code you didn't write, such as JavaScript libraries, into your git repo is a common practice, but **this often inflates your project's language stats and may even cause your project to be labeled as another language**.
>   By default, Linguist treats all of the paths defined in `vendor.yml` as vendored and therefore doesn't include them in the language statistics for a repository.
>
> Use the linguist-vendored attribute to vendor or un-vendor paths.

```
$ cat .gitattributes
special-vendored-path/* linguist-vendored
jquery.js linguist-vendored=false
```

Comment: Worked for me, although now wondering how this could *still* work on GitHub if .gitattribute is in .gitignore as GitHub obviously needs the file but I don't really want it in my repo any more…

Comment: In my case I wanted my GitHub profile's README.md to show up (as it was literally the only file in that repo anyway) so I created the .gitattributes with:
`*.md liguist-detectable`
 `README.md -linguist-documentation`
[details link](https://github.com/github/linguist#documentation)

Answer (score 41):

To make it simple, let me share my steps:

1. Change directory to your project root folder;
2. Create a file named *.gitattributes* using whatever tools of your choice:

   ```
    touch .gitattributes
   ```
3. Edit the file by following the [Linguist library](https://github.com/github/linguist) instructions to tell GitHub how to do it, for example:

   ```
    vi .gitattributes
   ```

   Using linguist-vendored can let GitHub know to "skip" detection for this folder and sub-folders:

   `src/main/resources/static/* linguist-vendored`

   Use the linguist-documentation attribute to mark or unmark paths as documentation:

   `project-docs/* linguist-documentation`

   OR mark an individual file containing documentation

   `documented_code.rb linguist-documentation=true`

   This is a bit weird, but you can do also -- to tell GitHub to treat some files with a specific extension (e.g., *.rb) as Java:

   `*.rb linguist-language=Java`
4. Git add, commit and then push it to GitHub. The label will be corrected almost immediately.

Comment: Worked for me, I have added below lines to my .gitattributes file

`*.java linguist-detectable=false
*.dart linguist-language=Dart
*.dart linguist-detectable=true
android/* linguist-vendored
build/* linguist-vendored`

Answer (score 25):

Replace your .gitattributes with this, which reclassifies **all** files as Java.

```
 *.* linguist-language=Java
```

[linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist#using-gitattributes)

Answer (score 20):

Create `.gitattributes` file in the root of your folder. Suppose you want the language to be Java, just copy-paste:

```yaml
*.java linguist-detectable=true
*.js linguist-detectable=false
*.html linguist-detectable=false
*.xml linguist-detectable=false
```

in the `.gitattributes` file and push the file in the repo. Refresh your GitHub page to see the language change.

**Note**: So, for the desired language make it true and other's false. It should work fine.

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid unexpected languages detection (by [filename extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension), or by project subfolder, etc.) by using the [GitHub linguist detectable option](https://github.com/github/linguist#detectable) in your `.gitattributes` file:

> Only programming languages are included in the language statistics. Languages of a different type (as defined in [`languages.yml`](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml)) are not "detectable" causing them not to be included in the language statistics.
>
> Use the `linguist-detectable` attribute to mark or unmark paths as detectable:
>
> ```ini
> *.kicad_pcb linguist-detectable=true
> *.sch linguist-detectable=true
> tools/export_bom.py linguist-detectable=false
> ```

Answer (score 4):

I had a project that was started in Objective-C and changed to Swift completely (new project, but in the same repository directory).
GitHub kept identifying it as Objective-C no matter what I used in file *.gitattributes* (all solutions in previous answers).

So, if the jig is up, and you're sure all the project is one language - you radically add:

```
# Direct Swift
*.* linguist-language=Swift
```

Only that fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

In the *.gitattributes* file just tell Linguist not to determine file languages which you don't want.

Example for ignoring JavaScript files:

```
*.js linguist-vendored
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is pretty simple:

just add these lines in your project terminal

1. `touch .gitattributes`

   After writing this command, the file *.gitattributes* should be found in project explorer. If this file does not appear, try to show hidden files to find it.
2. `*.* linguist-language=Java`

   Change Java with your target language -Swift in your case-
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit -m "Change tagged language from Java to Kotlin"`
5. `git push`

Now after refreshing the GitHub page, you should found the new update.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the language of the Laravel repository, then add the following line to your `.gitattributes` file:

```
*.blade.php linguist-vendored
```

GitHub defines [Blade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel#Features) files as HTML, but `*.html linguist-vendored` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The solution which was provided by the expert EamonnM who answered this question above worked in my project, but there are two significant things.

1. The language in the beginning of the second line of his code was the language you want instead of the language you dislike. Remember to distinguish it.
2. It seems that you could not type any space before the `*`. (For example, I should type `*.swift linguist-vendored=false` when I want to change my language into Swift.)

Answer (score 1):

I have problem with this also. I created .gitattributes in root of my project. I removed .js and .cs, but .html is still there. This is my *.gitattributes* file:

```
*.cs linguist-detectable=true
*.js linguist-detectable=false`
*.html linguist-detectable=false
*.xml linguist-detectable=false
```

When I add `* linguist-vendored`, I don't see anything on GitHub.

[image]

Answer:

It is still the same. *.html* is still shown.

Comment: I think the "quote" at the end of the second line (after false) breaks the file :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create file ".gitattributes" in the root folder.

If you want your git to detect only .java files, you can use:

```
*.java linguist-detectable=true
*.* linguist-detectable=false
```

The *.* means every other file should not be detected as language.
For those who want more than 2 languages to be detected, they can manipulate this file.

Comment: This ignores every language, switch the order of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named .gitattributes to your project root folder. Adding `{file_name} linguist-generated=true` can do the trick. In my case,

```
mvnw.cmd linguist-generated=true
mvnw linguist-generated=true
```

worked for me.