# What extensions does github support, for syntax highlighting and for code/language recognition?

Tags: github, glsl

For my Open GL shaders, GitHub seems to recognize fragment shader ( extension `.fs`) but not vertex shaders ( extension `.vs`)

Since GLSL has no defined extensions (it loads text) what is a good extension to use so I get my code recognized.

As an example my shaders [Example Shaders](https://github.com/rcorbish/city/tree/7bd5a80995a9a8823addcaa2a14d871e367f41d0/shaders)
Note how `.fs` looks pretty and `.vs` like plain text

Comment: btw. `syntax coloring` is called `syntax highlight` it might lead for better search results ...

Comment: @Ric Did my answer worked?

Comment: @VonC I tried the answer (add to .gitattributes )  w/o success. based on your answer, I could change vertex shader to *.vsh to get recognized

Comment: Do you mean you had to rename the files, giving them a vsh extension?

Comment: I added the .gitattributes as suggested. I did not try to rename

Answer (score 2):

See if a `.gitattributes` linguistic directive, as I mentioned in "[Github changes repository to wrong language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34715182/6309)", would be enough:

```
*.vs linguist-detectable
*.vs linguist-language=GLSL
```

[`lib/linguist/languages.yml`](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/0a7455166b14b0ba9b46deabdff5603592f737f7/lib/linguist/languages.yml#L1612-L1634) GLSL section does include "`.fs`", but no "`.vs`", only "`.vsh`"