# How to change the language in GitHub repo from asm to c sharp

Tags: git, github

I have uploaded a Xamarin Forms project in GitHub but it shows the language as asm  and java instead of C# i have adde the below code in a .gitattributes file but it does not work it again shows asm and not C#

```
*.csharp linguist-detectable=true  
*.java linguist-detectable=false  
*.js linguist-detectable=false  
*.html linguist-detectable=false  
*.xml linguist-detectable=false 
*.asm linguist-detectable=false
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the repository language stats are only updated when you push changes, and the results are cached for the lifetime of your repository.Here is a similar thread which maybe can help you :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713765/github-changes-repository-to-wrong-language

Comment: Ok now what should I do to change it

Comment: Are you sure your `C#` files have an extension `.csharp`? Probably it is `.cs`

Comment: Yes I uploaded my project by using git bash after completing it using visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [`Build your first Xamarin.Forms App`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/first-app/?pivots=windows), I believe you are dealing with `.cs` files and not `.csharp` files.

The updated `.gitattributes` file is as follows:

```
*.cs linguist-detectable=true  
*.java linguist-detectable=false  
*.js linguist-detectable=false  
*.html linguist-detectable=false  
*.xml linguist-detectable=false 
*.asm linguist-detectable=false
```

As noted in **Detectable** section in this [Readme](https://github.com/github/linguist/#using-gitattributes) for Linguist library (used by GitHub to detect the languages), languages are defined in [`languages.yml`](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml) which states the following for `C#` :

```
C#:
  type: programming
  ace_mode: csharp
  codemirror_mode: clike
  codemirror_mime_type: text/x-csharp
  tm_scope: source.cs
  color: "#178600"
  aliases:
  - csharp
  extensions:
  - ".cs"
  - ".cake"
  - ".csx"
  language_id: 42
```

As highlighted, the extensions allowed are `.cs`, `.cake` and `.csx`.

Comment: I just tested it , it works fine for me : [repo-link](https://github.com/Saurabh702/tempforlingtest), but I did notice an issue. When you first click on the link you might see different languages but when you reload it you will only see `C#`

Answer (score 0):

Now it works i removed the obj and debug folder from Android, UWP and Forms folder  and again added  the files in a new repo now it works fine.