# Cannot specify language in GitHub repository

Tags: github, paginator, gitattributes, github-linguist

I know that GitHub automatically determines a repository's language by looking a the type of files in the repository. It is however supposed to be possible to override this by editing the .gitattributes file in the repository's root, as suggested in [GitHub changes repository to the wrong language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713765/github-changes-repository-to-the-wrong-language).

But I'm unable to make this work, and no language is specified for my repository (supposed to be Javascript).

This is my .gitattributes file:

```
examples/* linguist-vendored
* linguist-vendored
*.js linguist-vendored=false
*.js linguist-detectable=true
*.js linguist-language=JavaScript
```

My repository is:

https://github.com/arnemorken/anypaginator

Comment: Does it work if you remove the second line from your `.gitattributes` file?

Comment: @pchaigno No. But if I do that, it sets CSS as the language, so there's something going on there. I have tried many other variations, but no luck. The repository has only one CSS and one (much larger) Javascript file.

Comment: Then remove the second line and add `*.css linguist-vendored`.

Comment: @pchaigno Yes, I already tried that, but no cigar. That is, it reverts to showing no language.

Comment: Ah, right. Makes sense. Did you try to remove the last line? It shouldn't be needed AFAICT. If that doesn't work, then you're best bet is probably to run `github-linguist --breakdown` against your repository and check the results.