# How to add support for my programming language on GitHub?

Tags: github, programming-languages, github-linguist

I have my own programming language, and I want to make it appear in the list of languages in a repository. However, I can't find any answers to this question in the documentation. Can someone please provide guidance and explain how to achieve this?

I've been searching through GitHub forums and official documentation but haven't been able to find a solution. I'm trying to make my programming language appear in the repository's list of languages. Can someone please provide guidance and explain how to achieve this since I couldn't find the information in the GitHub documentation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add custom language to a GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593670/add-custom-language-to-a-github-repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub uses the Linguist library to recognize the languages. The process to add support for a new language in Linguist is documented at https://github.com/github-linguist/linguist/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#adding-a-language.

Note that **they require the language to be used in 200 unique GitHub repositories** before adding support.