# Changing repository language on GitHub

Tags: github, github-linguist

I've noticed that Github picked JavaScript as the language for my Django app:

[image]

Is it possible to change it to Python? Or do I need to make a new repository?

---

Solved:

As @Geno Chen said, to change the repository language we have to add the file .gitattributes containing this code:

```
# to change language of repo from Javascript to Python
    *.js linguist-language=Python
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github language tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305147/github-language-tag)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the language of a repository on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597892/how-to-change-the-language-of-a-repository-on-github)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github changes repository to wrong language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34713765/3345375)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [language detector](https://github.com/github/linguist) stats the programs in your projects and shows the result with the ratio. If your repository have detected a wrong language, you can [follow the tutorial](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#my-repository-is-detected-as-the-wrong-language), most of the time you just need to [override](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/docs/overrides.md) the result with a `.gitattributes` in the repository root containing something like the sample from tutorial, to manually pull up the ratio of specific programming language:

```
# Example of a `.gitattributes` file which reclassifies `.rb` files as Java:
*.rb linguist-language=Java
```

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. I'm using tailwind CSS for my JS based web project. It shows 97% css and rest as JS. I've added *.js linguist-language=JavaScript inside ".gitattributes" but it didn't fix

Comment: @vikramvi Asking GitHub for seeing JS files as  JavaScript files are obviously useless. It seems you need to ask GitHub for seeing **CSS** files as JavaScript files.

Comment: *.css linguist-detectable=false fixed partially as CSS is shown 0% with this, not sure if there is bug with GH language detection library

Answer (score 10):

Create a new file in your repo and name it to `.gitattributes`. After that make sure you set `linguist-detectable` to `true`like this:

```
*.css linguist-detectable=false
*.java linguist-detectable=false
*.python linguist-detectable=true 
*.js linguist-detectable=false
*.html linguist-detectable=false  
*.xml linguist-detectable=false
```

Comment: simple and straightforward answer. It perfectly worked for me

Comment: makes more sense than the accepted answer thank you