# How to change language tag in github repository?

Tags: github, kotlin

I wrote my applications on Kotlin, but github shows Java, how can i change it?
[image: github shows java]

[image: but code written in Kotlin]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing repository language on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54946235/changing-repository-language-on-github)

Comment: @Lemmy, thank you, worked